# problem with variable in ruby

Tags: ruby

Excuse I am newbie in ruby.

My problem is about argument passes by value and reference.

I am coding this method

```
def show_as_tree(parents)
  array = []
  iterate_categories(parents, array)
end

def iterate_categories(parents, array)
  parents.each do |p|
    #return p.description or "-#{p.description} if the node is root or not
    p.description = category_name(p)

    #add to array
    array << p

    #call iterate categories with children of parent node and same array
    iterate_categories(p.children, array)
  end
end
```

however the array content is only the parent nodes.

I need understand the ruby mechanism for references and how could fix my problem?

Comment: You can use object_id method on any object to get answer for your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure Ruby just creates a copy of your array. Therefore what you should be doing is having

```
array << iterate_categories(p.children, new_array)
```

And return your array at the end of the function.

Just did a quick example: (Updating code based on Wayne Conrad's answer… it is correct)

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :children
end

class Test

  def iterate_categories(parents,array)
    parents.each do |p|
      array << p.name
      if !p.children.nil?
        iterate_categories(p.children,array)
      end
    end
  end

  def iterate_categories_test
    p1 = Person.new
    p1.name = "Bob"

    p2 = Person.new
    p2.name = "Joe"

    p3 = Person.new
    p3.name = "Ann"

    p4 = Person.new
    p4.name = "John"

    p1.children = [p2,p3]
    p3.children = [p4]

    array = []
    iterate_categories([p1],array)
    puts array
  end
end
```

Then:

```
>> a = Test.new
>> a.iterate_categories_test
Bob
Joe
Ann
John
=> nil
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Actually, ruby passes arguments by reference, but also performs a copy-on-write: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/41160

Comment: @Kris, I think that's incorrect.  Ruby does not do copy-on-write.  Variables are (conceptually, at least) references.  When you call a method, references to the values you pass in the argument list are assigned to the arguments.  And a mutable object can have its state changed through messages (method calls) sent to it via its reference.  That's pretty much it.

Comment: This solution works not because ruby was copying `array` (it wasn't), but because it properly returns `array` from the function.

Answer (score 1):

Your show_as_tree method should return the array.

```
def show_as_tree(parents)
  array = []
  iterate_categories(parents, array)
  array
end
```

Without `array` as the last line, the return value of `show_as_tree` is the return value of `iterate_categories`, which happens to be `parents`.  That's why it looks like only `parents` is getting added to `array`.  That's an illusion: It was `parents` being returned, not `array`.

Ruby does not make copies of its arguments.  It *passes references by value*.  That means it is the same array being acted upon throughout your functions.

Comment: Good to know. Learn something new every day. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get the code, the formatting seems all wrong but I'll try to help.

When you pass an argument to ruby, it seems to give the method a copy, not a reference. Fortunately, you don't need to worry about that, as ruby lets you return multiple things in one call.

For example, in irb I ran something like this:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :005 > def stuff(a, b)
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :006?>   c = a + b
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007?>   [c, a]
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008?>   end
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009 > a, b = stuff(1, 2)
 => [3, 1] 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > a
 => 3 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 > b
 => 1
```

That way you can easily return multiple values without problem

I hope I answered your question.

Comment: Ruby does copy its arguments, but what it is copying are *references*.